# running script containing sudo in cron

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu, cron, sudo

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(<man.txt)
echo "$value"

if [ "$value" == "true" ]; then
    echo "startedif_manthan"
      ps -ef|grep sym |awk '{ print $2 }'|sudo  xargs kill -9;
      sleep 30;
    sudo sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server;
fi
```

I need to run above script in cron. Will it execute in cron without password?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can edit the crontab as root (not really recommended)?

Comment: [Better answer for the same question](http://superuser.com/a/551967/235231) and [another duplicate](http://serverfault.com/questions/478690/running-script-containing-sudo-in-cron)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/etc/sudoers` to select which commands could be run as sudo without needing password.

Warning: do not edit it manually, edit it using `visudo`.

Comment: Well I'm trying to edit /etc/sudoers it showed permission denied. Can you help me out how to do this please?

Comment: I used sudo visudo to edit the file but. What command should I include to make my script run using sudo without password.